# Flash Builder cannot locate the required version of Adobe Flash Player

Tags: flex4, flash

Im using flex 4
While running a application i got this error

> Flash Builder cannot locate the required version of Adobe Flash
>   Player. You might need to install the Flash Player or reinstall Flash
>   Builder.

Which version flash player required for flex 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved...I have clicked Link  'flash player downloads' on the error message then downloaded and  installed Flash Player 10.3

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this thread at Adobe Forums - http://forums.adobe.com/thread/606832

The above thread is about the exact error message.

In all there are following things suggested in the thread.

1.

> Associate the Flash Debug player as the standalone player with SWF
>   files.

2.

> To use HTML wrapper, just right click on your project and select
>   'properties'. Select 'Actionscript Compiler' on the left column, and
>   in the resulting properties pane on the right, check the option for
>   'Generate HTML Wrapper File'. That should force FB to launch the web
>   browser for debug. This will require the ActiveX or Mozilla flash
>   debug player, depending on which browser you're using for debugging.

3.

> I did a search in the registry and found two instances where Flex was referrenced rather that Flash builder changing this  to flash builder seemed to eliminate the problem.

Comment: yes same problem but i didn't get solution from that :( when i click yes   An internal error occurred during: Launching  will disply.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion.. but that methods didn't help me.. but I got solution by installing the flashplayer 10.3 :)