# Flash Builder cannot locate the required debugger version of Adobe Flash Player

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe, builder

I'm running Flash Builder 4, with Flex 4.5.1 (also have 4.1, 4.0 and 3.5) and I receive this error when I debug...

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\NPSWF32.dll
Flash Builder cannot locate the required debugger version of Adobe Flash Player. You might need to install the debugger version of the Flash Player or reinstall Flash Builder.
Do you want to try to debug with the current version?

I managed to fix this by installing the Flash Player 10 debugger, but... Flash player 11 is the latest and it causes the above error.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and/or know how to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got The Same problem but My problem was solved by installing flash player 10.3 
[Refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499015/flash-builder-cannot-locate-the-required-version-of-adobe-flash-player)and
[youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhBCQiyQGvw&feature=player_detailpage)

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes see the problem when you're not generating the html content and just try to run the SWF directly.  When that happens, it tries to run it on the standalone player.  Either run it through the browser by using HTML or make sure you download the [Flash Player Projector content debugger](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) and copy it over your current system flash player (either in the Flash Builder sdk directory or your own sdk directory).

Answer (score 2):

There setting for this in Flash Builder is in Window -> Preferences -> Flash Builder -> Debug.

Comment: I'm looking at those settings right now. Can you explain which settings you mean? None of them seem to be able to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

On another thread (at Adobe) I just read that if you are using Chrome, that the 'debugger' version of flash installed keeps getting replaced by the 'non-debugger' standard version behind the scenes (without you being asked)...

Perhaps this is whats afoot with your enviroment if you are using Chrome as your default browser.

Also, I do think there is a method to turn off this automatic updating behavior inside of Chrome once you get it setup as you wish.

Hope this helps. Cheers //GH